# Make loaded library use different classloader

Tags: android, dex

I am developing an android app.

I have a ClassLoader which has a huge budle of classes, and a library which uses it via JNI.

I can't add those classes as **jar**, because those are too big, and it throws **Unable to execute dex**.
If I enable **multidex**, its compilation takes 3 minutes, and **overflows**.

How can I load library as a different classloader?